# How can I open a .xlsx file from ASP.Net Server?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, xls, xlsx

I'm trying to open up .xlsx files generated from our servers because I've been requested to change the files from .xls to .xlsx. There was no problem with the old version, they just wanted to upgrade. I've tried and I've searched many tips and sites where people are asking the same question but no one gave them a correct answer and the latest I've found was around 2012. Here is most likely the main problem.

```
Public Sub GenerateExcelToBrowser(ByRef dtDetailRows As DataTable, _
                                          ByVal strReportname As String, _
                                                Optional ByRef dtHeaderRow As DataTable = Nothing, _
                                                Optional ByVal blnMissingPartsOverride As Boolean = False, _
                                                Optional ByVal Scheduler As String = "N")
            Dim Response As System.Web.HttpResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response
            Try
                Dim sbHTML As New StringBuilder

                sbHTML = GenerateExcel(dtDetailRows, strReportname, dtHeaderRow, blnMissingPartsOverride)

                Response.Clear()
                Response.Charset = String.Empty
                Response.Buffer = True
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", strReportname)) 'set the response mime type for excel
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                Response.Write(sbHTML.ToString())            
                Response.Flush()
            Catch MemEx As OutOfMemoryException
                Dim oLog4Net As clsLog4Net = New clsLog4Net
                oLog4Net.LogError(MemEx.Message.ToString() & " - " & MemEx.Source.ToString() & " - " & MemEx.StackTrace.ToString())
                Response.Write("The report you are trying to create contains more information than can be sent. Please narrow the report criteria and try again.")
                Response.Flush()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim oLog4Net As clsLog4Net = New clsLog4Net
                If UCase(Scheduler) = "Y" Then
                    oLog4Net.LogError(ex.Message.ToString() & " - " & ex.Source.ToString() & " - " & ex.StackTrace.ToString())
                    Response.Write("Error on a page. For assistance please call CSA Today Administrator at 877-422-4225.")
                Else
                    oLog4Net.LogError(ex.Message.ToString() & " - " & ex.Source.ToString() & " - " & ex.StackTrace.ToString())
                End If
                oLog4Net = Nothing
                Response.Flush()
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Simply renaming the file is not enough. Excel 2013 will say the file format/extension is not valid and check if it is corrupted. I have compared the properties between the new and old types. Under "Details" the new type lacks a name,type, and folderpath. I've been hitting my head on this for day and I don't know why such a simple sounding task can end up so complicated.

Any information will be much appreciated!

Comment: ...renaming a file extension doesn't change the type of the file at all. You will need a file conversion library like Aspose. Do not use the Office Automation Components (`Interop.Excel` etc) in server-side applications as they are unsupported.

Comment: You weren't creating true `.xls` files in the first place. They were just HTML files being served with a `.xls` extension. To create true .xlsx files, you'll need to use a library such as Open XML SDK, NPOI, or EPPlus (my favorite).

Comment: @Dai Yes I found that out my first time around. I will look into the conversion library you mentioned. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @mason Thank you for the tip. Is there anyway to make an HTML file with the .xlsx extension though? The xls file still created a spreadsheet of the stored data the user wanted.

Comment: @user2105171 No. Please learn about the formats you're trying to use so that you understand their capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007 and beyond use a file format called "OpenXML".  You will need to update your `GenerateExcel` method to produce a file in that format.  You can look at several different libraries to do this.  [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) is one that I have used in the past, and [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) is popular as well.  There are also others if you search around.

Also, you can't "open the file from the server", as it were.  You can only push the file to the browser, at which point it becomes the responsibility of the browser and the user can choose to open it, save it, or discard it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to convert your XLS file into XLSX format. You can do it using Aspose.Cells with the simple line of code like the following

```
string filePath = @"c:\source.xls";
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(filePath);
workbook.Save(@"c:\output.xlsx", SaveFormat.Xlsx);
```

You do not need to import data from your xls file and then export it to your xlsx file. Just simply load your xls file inside a workbook object and save it in xlsx format.

Also you can use this solution in your ASP.NET in Server Side. You can also load and save your workbook in different formats in memory stream.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'm using Aspose right now. I'm doing what you're telling me but the error "cannot find" whatever my filepath name is and it just saves the xls file. So I am unsure of where to put it within the code. For the filepath, I have  Dim filePath As String = "c:\\" + strReportname and the document's name is "Advanced Charges.xls"

Comment: Please try the following code. First give the hardcoded path. Once you are successfully able to convert your file, then try using variable path.

Dim filePath as string = "c:\source.xls"
Dim workbook as Workbook = new Workbook(filePath)
workbook.Save("c:\output.xlsx", SaveFormat.Xlsx)